# LINQ : WHERE clause not working after GROUPBY AND SELECT

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Firstly, I am getting Debits(Non-grouped) from the database.

```
var groupingData = await adminService.GetDebitsGrouping();
```

And then, I am grouping the Debits according to types(Remittance or Non-Remittance).

```
//Grouping non-remittance records
        var groupedCustomerList = groupingData
            .GroupBy(u => new { u.MemberId, u.CurrencyType, u.AccountToPay, u.SortCodeOrBIC })
            .Select(grp => new DebitsGroupingViewModel
            {
                PaymentOutId = grp.FirstOrDefault().PaymentOutId,
                Sector = grp.FirstOrDefault().Sector,
                MemberId = grp.FirstOrDefault().MemberId,
                MemberName = grp.FirstOrDefault().MemberName,
                SupplierName = grp.FirstOrDefault().SupplierName,
                AccountToPay = grp.FirstOrDefault().AccountToPay,
                SortCodeOrBIC = grp.FirstOrDefault().SortCodeOrBIC,
                Transactions = grp.Sum(x => x.Transactions),
                TotalToPay = grp.Sum(x => x.TotalToPay),
                CurrencyType = grp.FirstOrDefault().CurrencyType,
                ClientCurrency = grp.FirstOrDefault().ClientCurrency,
                AccountName = grp.FirstOrDefault().AccountName,
                SupplierId = grp.FirstOrDefault().SupplierId,
                SupplierTypeId = grp.FirstOrDefault().SupplierTypeId,
                PayTypeMasterId = grp.FirstOrDefault().PayTypeMasterId,
                ClientReferenceNumber = grp.FirstOrDefault().ClientReferenceNumber
            })       
            .Where(x => x.PayTypeMasterId.GetValueOrDefault() != -1)
            .ToList();
```

But it seems that `WHERE` clause is not working properly. It includes some of the Non-Remittance records too.

I also tried searching the web before asking but did not find the correct reason/answer.

**NOTE** : All Non-Remittance records have id other than -1.

Comment: Swap `where` with `groupby`

Comment: `groupingData.Where( .. ).GroupBy( .. ).Select( .. ).ToList();`

Comment: Also check that the default value is -1, the default for value types is generally 0

Comment: @FortyTwo It works if I write Where before GroupBy. Can you please explain why it is working now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LINQ to objects, the statement is directly turned into a series of method calls:

When you do the following:

```
var result = myData.GroupBy( .. ).Select( .. ).Where( .. ).ToList();
```

This gets translated into something like this:

```
var result = Enumerable.ToList(
                Enumerable.Where(
                    IGrouping.GroupBy( .. )
                )
            );
```

This is not what we want. We want to filter `myData` and then group it instead of grouping the data and then filtering it. So when you change the order:

```
var result = myData.Where( .. ).GroupBy( .. ).Select( .. ).ToList();
```

This gets translated into something like this:

```
var result = Enumerable.ToList(
                IGrouping.GroupBy(
                    Enumerable.Where( .. )
                )
            );
```

Now we are achieving what we want, filter first (innermost call) and then group our data.

Hope this helps. Additionally, you can read [Query Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/query-keywords) for more details on `group` and `where` clauses